# Pandas DataFrame.corr() doesn't give same results as Series.corr()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two timeseries

```
jpm  = pd.read_csv(...) # JPM GBI Global All Traded
msci = pd.read_csv(...) # MSCI WORLD U$
```

Together in a DataFrame they look like

```
df = jpm.merge(msci, how='outer', on='Date', sort=True)
df
```

|  | Date | JPM GBI Global All Traded | MSCI WORLD U$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1970-01-01 | NaN | 100.0 |
| 1 | 1970-01-02 | NaN | 100.0 |
| 2 | 1970-01-05 | NaN | 100.0 |
| 3 | 1970-01-06 | NaN | 100.0 |
| 4 | 1970-01-07 | NaN | 100.670 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 13838 | 2023-01-17 | 492.3360 | 2736.452 |
| 13839 | 2023-01-18 | 496.4402 | 2713.537 |
| 13840 | 2023-01-19 | 494.9905 | 2685.317 |
| 13841 | 2023-01-20 | 492.3206 | 2725.396 |
| 13842 | 2023-01-23 | 491.5816 | 2754.961 |

I want to compute the correlation between the two timeseries.

**Using DataFrame.corr()**:

```
corr1 = df.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1, numeric_only=True)
corr1
```

|  | JPM GBI Global All Traded | MSCI WORLD U$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **JPM GBI Global All Traded** | 1.000000 | 0.849705 |
| **MSCI WORLD U$** | 0.849705 | 1.000000 |

Correlation is `0.849705`

**Using Series.corr()**:

```
s1 = jpm['JPM GBI Global All Traded']#.dropna()
s2 = msci['MSCI WORLD U$']#.dropna()
corr2 = s1.corr(s2, method='pearson', min_periods=1)
corr2
```

Correlation is `0.904641`

---

As you can see the two correlations don't match even though they should. And I've also tried applying the .dropna() function manually but it makes no difference.

And according to the [pandas.DataFrame.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) documentation:

> Compute pairwise correlation of columns, excluding NA/null values.

Is it a bug with my code or with pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out and it had to do with my **indexes not being aligned**.

## Example using aligned indexes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [1,1,2,4]})

s1 = df['A']
s2 = df['B']
df
```

```
    A   B
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   3   2
3   4   4
```

**DataFrame.corr()**:

```
corr1 = df.corr()
corr1
```

```
           A           B
A   1.000000    0.912871
B   0.912871    1.000000
```

Correlation is `0.912871`

**Series.corr()**:

```
corr2 = s1.corr(s2)
corr2
```

Correlation is `0.912871`

## Example using misaligned indexes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [1,1,2,4]}, index=[1,2,3,4])

s1 = df['A'].reset_index(drop=True)
s2 = df['B']
df
```

```
    A   B
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   3   2
4   4   4
```

**DataFrame.corr()**:

```
corr1 = df.corr()
corr1
```

```
           A           B
A   1.000000    0.912871
B   0.912871    1.000000
```

Correlation is `0.912871`

**Series.corr()**:

```
corr2 = s1.corr(s2)
corr2
```

Correlation is `0.866025`

---

The reason we get a different result in the second example is because [pandas.Series.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html) will only compute the correlation for **rows with matching index**.